# Regular Expression to not consider an element in one specific location

Tags: php, regex, magento

I need a regular expression to match this type of string 99999-111

I have written this ^[\D.]*([^\D.][\D.]*){8}$

But I need that only when the hyphen at that specific location is not written to be also accepted. So I need to accept both 99999-111 or 99999111 but **NOT** 99-999-111 or 99-999b111 for example. Please, any suggestions?

Comment: Are these numeric values of fixed length?  What exactly is the criteria you are trying to match?  Based on what I understood from your question, `^[0-9]{5}[\-]?[0-9]{3}$`?

Comment: It is brazilian Postal code, your code does work too! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the following work for you?
`([\d]{5}-?[\d]{3})`
I tested it [here](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/lTc).

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much!